# How do I load a file as entity knowing its full path?

Tags: files

I want to replace a file entity while uploading it via `hook_entity_insert()`.

1. I upload a file using its full path, for example /var/www/web/sites/default/files/test.png
2. I convert it to some another format, for example /var/www/web/sites/default/files/test.jpeg
3. I want to replace the default entity file with a new entity pointing to the converted image

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is this with the aim of displaying the converted images? A possible alternative is you could use Drupal's image styles convert functionality to change the format on output (use an image style to output your image)

Comment: In order to answer your question, I need more information. How do you upload the source file? do you create an entity of the source file and you need to replace it with the new one? What do you mean by replacing? is it replacing the file name in the entity or creating a new entity and deleting the old one?

Comment: @HodbaKhalaf I create node with image field. What I want is replace a file by a new file entity (on upload process I run convertation to another format and have a new file, but not a file entity. For example: I want replace uploaded file of filename.jpf by a new created file filename.png for example. As I understand after some time of testing this hook will be not correct to use in this case as it is can't change anyway node after submitting form.

Comment: @Leigh thanks for answer. I'll try go in that way too.